# Parallax scrolling without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, parallax

I wanted to know if there are some javascript libraries that handles parallax scrolling, with panes, but without using scrollbars ? 
My client doesn't want any scrollbars and the website works like panels that show when you scroll.

I tried Skrollr, but when I overflow : hidden, it doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: You can have an outer div and an inner div.Set the width and height of the outer div to a specific value and set `overflow:hidden` . And in the inner div , but your content.

Comment: thanks but the problem remains because I need to set an overflow : hidden to the <body> to remove the scrollbar. And when I do, it doesn't detect the scroll..

Comment: It's actually working when I trigger a scrollTop with jquery with a button. Sorry for that question and thanks :)

Comment: glad that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you always have to write some code to "parallax" the whole thing , but, I once used this library

**jQuery mousewheel**
https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

because I did not want `scrollbar`'s in my website , it was really helpful. It allows you to detect `scrolling` in every `div` of your `document` , so you're not obliged to bind action to `window.scroll`. 
The only issue if you're not using *jQuery* is that this library requires it.
Anyway I think that *jQuery* is always a good idea.